# Já alguém conseguiu integrar o plugin card.io num projecto cordova para android?

Tags: android, apache-cordova, plugin

Estou a tentar fazer uma integração do plugin [Card.io](https://www.card.io) num projecto Cordova para Android e o único reservatório que encontrei foi [este](https://github.com/freakypie/card.io-phonegap) e as instruções não estão coerentes com o zip (nomeadamente o nome de uma das pastas).

Será que alguém por aí já conseguiu fazer esta integração e me pode ajudar?

Agradeço desde já a ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

O plugin que eu utilizei foi o "cordova-plugin-keepe-cardio" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-keepe-cardio), e ele foi realmente muito fácil de configurar na plataforma android. 
Com este, tu podes apenas rodar o comando:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-keepe-cardio
```

E ele já vai estar pronto para usar.

No link acima tem um tutorial bem explicado, por sinal.

Vou colocar o texto original aqui para o caso de o link original quebrar (infelizmente não vou poder traduzi-lo por motivos de tempo hábil):

### Sample HTML + JS

1. In ScanCard/www/index.html add the following to lines after `<p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>`:

`<button id="scanBtn"> Scan Now!</button>`

2. Replace `ScanCard/www/js/index.js` with the following code:

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
var app = {
    // Application Constructor 
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners 
    // 
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are: 
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'. 
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler 
    // 
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent' 
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);' 
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event 
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);

        app.example();
    },

    example : function () {
      var cardIOResponseFields = [
        "card_type",
        "redacted_card_number",
        "card_number",
        "expiry_month",
        "expiry_year",
        "cvv",
        "zip"
      ];

      var onCardIOComplete = function(response) {
        console.log("card.io scan complete");
        for (var i = 0, len = cardIOResponseFields.length; i < len; i++) {
          var field = cardIOResponseFields[i];
          console.log(field + ": " + response[field]);
        }
      };

      var onCardIOCancel = function() {
        console.log("card.io scan cancelled");
      };

      var onCardIOCheck = function (canScan) {
        console.log("card.io canScan? " + canScan);
        var scanBtn = document.getElementById("scanBtn");
        if (!canScan) {
          scanBtn.innerHTML = "Manual entry";
        }
        scanBtn.onclick = function (e) {
          CardIO.scan({
                "expiry": true,
                "cvv": true,
                "zip": true,
                "suppressManual": false,
                "suppressConfirm": false,
                "hideLogo": true
            },
            onCardIOComplete,
            onCardIOCancel
          );
        }
      };

      CardIO.canScan(onCardIOCheck);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Boa sorte!